# Running Click event with no result

Tags: html, vba, onclick, click

Can someone explain to me why when I click on the following element, the form is not sent. The element is identified however there is no result. 
This is the part of the code i am interested in solving, everything up to this point is running fine.

```
Set IEDoc = Internet.document

Set collection = IEDoc.getElementsByTagName("input") ' there are actually 9 elements

For Each Element In collection
    If Element.Type = "image" Then ' there is only the element of interest in here
        Element.Click


        End If
Next
```

Here is a sample of the HTML code from the webpage:

[image: html code]

Comment: Yeah, because this part of code `javascript:return false;`

Comment: Can I somehow turn it True so that the click event becomes effective ?

Comment: No, you can't do it with VBA...my guest is that the method is handled via javascript or jquery in another place...can you post the url in order to inspect the code?

Comment: Unfortunately you won't be able to access it since it is from my intranet, but here is the code on a bigger scale

Comment: Ok, I see a `form` in there...are you sure that there is no submit button, somewhere?

Comment: no button of type submit in the code nope. 2 ways to manually submit the form : 1 ) by clicking the button display ( which is my issue) 2) with the cell _operation_ selected by pressing enter ( so I guess I can also use this method in the code somehow but I thought it was even harder) (see the picture I just added from the webpage)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bigger scale of the HTML code from the page in which we can see the form containing the button to submit the information.[html code bigger scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4ffJ.png)

[user interface of the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svjOY.png)