# How to click on that form?

Tags: html, vba

I am not familiar with html and I am trying to submit a form from VBA.
I managed to select it, but then is there a special command to send it ?

[image: This is what the form looks like.].

I tried to click on it to submit it, but this doesn't work.

```
IEDoc.getElementsByTagName("form")(0).Click
```

I know my attempts sound poor, but I was at first trying to click on element which had a onclick property which returns false and I didn't manage to get this to work.
I found an other solution which worked but made the whole code crash at some point, this solution was to use the SendKeys method. You can see the article

[Running Click event with no result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40492161/running-click-event-with-no-result)

my colleague posted about it

Any tips are welcome.

EDIT : [Bigger picture of the HTML code with full form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJqAw.png)

Comment: Have you tried, .submit?

Comment: I have tried IEDoc.getElementsByTagName("form")(0).Submit however I knew this wouldnt work as the property doesent exist in the form. Is there another option I could try?

Comment: Have you tried using the HTML and Internet libraries, the you can assign form(0) to a formobject, and truly look at the properties using locals/intellisense https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms970672.aspx

Comment: I selected both Internet Controls and HTML Object libraries references. `Dim My_Form As HTMLFormElement 'Variant 'IHTMLFormElement
 'rest of the code
 MsgBox TypeName(IEDoc.getElementsByTagName("form")(0)) ' returns HTMLFormElement`
 `My_Form = IEDoc.getElementsByTagName("form")(0) ' 1) if declaring My_Form as a IHTMLFormElement I get "Type Mismatch" on that line 2) if declaring My_Form as a HTMLFormElement I get a "Run-time error '91' : Object variable or With blick variable not set" 3)  if declaring My_Form as a Variant , this line works but of course My_Form.Click doesn't do anything`

Comment: `My_Form.Click
 IEDoc.getElementsByName("knopf")(0).Click ' nothing happens when clicking on a random element of the form`

Comment: Can you post the URL?

Comment: It's an intranet URL so it won t work for you, but  I edit my post and will put a bigger picture of the HTML code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I'd go about it, using SO as the URL

```
Sub x()

Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim f As MSHTML.HTMLFormElement

Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba"

Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or ie.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop

Set f = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("form")(0)
f.elements(0).value="SQL"
f.submit

End Sub
```

Comment: Nathan you legend, it worked perfectly. Declaring the form this way enabled the Intellisense from VBA and activated the "submit" property ! Thanks so much

Comment: No worries, I know that chaining together is allowed and easy enough to do, but readability and intellisense with some of them, it helps to break it up.  You can spend hours debugging otherwise. :)

Comment: Thanks man, I would up-vote your answer but unfortunately I dont have enough reputation yet haha